# graphql server for external REST API

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, graphql

i want to build a react-native app.
The content of the app is nearly 100% caught by an external REST API.

Because its very beginner unfriendly because of many different endpoints and so many calls to recieve one result i read i bit about graphql which only requires on query to get everything we want.

So i had the idea to build my own graphql server with mongodb as database.
On this server i fetch the data of the external REST and write it to the database.

Then i make this data available through graphql queries. Probably by deploying this server to heroku?

So my question is:
Is this a common way to make the api calls easier or isnt that even worth to develop because in the end i have no benefit of it?

I would love to hear everybodys opinion on this and would be very thankful for any type of tip.

Comment: It doesn't has to write anything to DB (it can), you can just return data collected from REST, even many of them, local or remote. Think about this as a kind of proxy, it can be caching (in memory?), there would be many benefits. Read about **schema stitching**.

Comment: Okay, thank you, is heroku a good place to run this? or is there a problem with the free plan and the sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity

Comment: Heroku would be fine. If you don't want your users to deal with timeouts, you can set up a free healthcheck endpoint to ping your server to keep it alive, but you'll have to pay at the end of the month if it doesn't sleep.